# Java string — как организовать цикл по строке?

Tags: java, строки, циклы

У меня есть строка `abcd*tt()uyuy*u()yuy`

Можно ли заменить `*tt()` и `*u()` на `edit` и `reduce`?

Проблема вся в том, что для задания важен порядок в котором встречаются эти конструкции.

Что-то вроде запускаем цикл по строке и если встретили `*tt()`, то необходимо выполнить одно действие, если встретили `*u()`, то выполняем другое действие, если ни одной из заранее заданных конструкций не встретили, то просто идем дальше по строке. Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

**P.S.** строка может быть любой, но в ней встречаются такие конструкции случайным образом.

Comment: Смотрите документацию, прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Для начала метод replaceAll вам в помощь.

Comment: a_gura, для меня важен порядок, в котором я их заменяю, т.к строка может быть любой.

Comment: @aaaadsdsdasd, посмотрите на метод `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` для String.

Ну, циклы, пока оба `from_ttIndex = str.indexOf("tt()", from_ttIndex)` и `from_uIndex = str.indexOf("u()", from_uIndex)` не станут равны -1 и поиск меньшего из `from_uIndex` и `from_ttIndex` на каждой итерации первого из циклов, думаю, напишите сами?

Comment: @aaaadsdsdasd и что вам мешает реализовать замену с учетом порядка? Посмотрите на методы в документации, подумайте и наверняка придумаете решение.

Answer (score 2):

Какой цикл по строке?
Используйте replace.

```
String s = "abcdtt()tt()uyuyu()yuy";
s = s.replace("tt()","edit").replace("u()","reduce");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: для меня важен порядок, в котором я их заменяю, т.к строка может быть любой.

Answer (score 1):

Если вас не устраивает `replace` (например, вы не просто хотите заменить текст в строках, а сделать что-то ещё), то наиболее просто (хотя не суперэффективно) — использовать `String.startsWith(prefix, offset)`:

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ) {
    if(s.startsWith("u()", i)) {
        // обрабатываем u()
        System.out.println("reduce");
        i+="u()".length();
    } else if(s.startsWith("tt()", i)) {
        // обрабатываем tt()
        System.out.println("edit");
        i+="tt()".length();
    } else {
        // ничего интересного в данной позиции
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```